# Connect Azure DevOps to Azure subscription

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have created an Azure DevOps organization for my company and I am trying to link this to our Azure subscription. I have followed the chat bot's instructions:

- Sign in to your organization ([https://dev.azure.com/{yourorganization}](https://dev.azure.com/%7Byourorganization%7D)).
- Select  Organization settings.​
- Select Billing.​
- Select Set up billing.​
- Select your Azure subscription, and then select Save.​
- Billing is now setup

However, no subscription information is coming up.

**Note**:

(1) I am using the same Microsoft account that I do for the Azure portal

(2) When I log into the portal with these credentials, I can find the DevOps organisation under 'my organisations'

(3) I have 'owner' status on the subscription

(4) When I set up a pipeline via Visual Studio, both DevOps organisation and Azure subscription were picked up.

Could anyone tell me what is going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: If you look at the billing page of your DevOps organization, does any subscription show up? Maybe a screenshot of what you're seeing would be helpful - also what type of subscription do you have?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue and stumbled upon a solution. Posting it here in case someone else finds this post as I did via Google.

1. Go to https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com/
2. Check to see which account your organization is on - see link below

[image: Drop down list]

The organization I had set up was associated with my Microsoft account. I created a new organization in the Default Directory and it found the subscription in Billing.

I'm a student so it was no problem for me to start over with a new organization. I don't know how one would transfer an existing org to the correct account if needed.